# Is there syntax for moving fields between similar structs?

Tags: syntax, rust

I have a big struct `Foo<Q>`, and want to `map` it into a `Foo<R>` where most of the fields don't need updating. I was hoping to use the `..` operator for this, but it is a type error, as they are technically different types.

That is, given:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    a: usize,
    b: usize,
    t: T,
}

let q: Foo<Q>;
```

I would like to write:

```
let r = Foo::<R> {
    t: fixup(q.t),
    ..q
};
```

But, this gives me a type error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
 3 |         ..q
   |           ^ expected struct `R`, found struct `Q`
   |
   = note: expected type `Foo<R>`
              found type `Foo<Q>`
```

The type error is reasonable, as the types can be thought of as templates in this case.

The only workaround I have is to write out the transformation in full, which gets ugly quite quickly:

```
let r = Foo::<R> {
    a: q.a,
    b: q.b,
    t: fixup(q.t),
};
```

Here's [a playground with a full test-case](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=31e08cf60d480dee87beb61f818d1167&version=stable&mode=debug), including the compile error and the long-form.

---

Is there better syntax for this somewhere, or a better way to implement these `map`-like methods for non-trivial structs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there syntax for moving fields between similar structs?

No. There is no such syntax. The current implementation of "struct update" (previously called "functional record update") syntax only allows the exact same type.

> Is there better syntax for this somewhere, or a better way to implement these map-like methods for non-trivial structs?

No. The only suggestion I have is to destructure your original struct and then recreate it. You also don't need the `::<R>` as it's inferred.

```rust
let Foo { a, b, c, d, e, t } = q;
let r = Foo {
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    t: fixup(t),
};
```

See also:

- [RFC 2528 — Type-changing struct update syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2528)
- [Issue #47741 — Struct initializer `..x` syntax should work for other structs with structurally equal subset of fields](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47741)
- Similar issue: [Struct update syntax for different types](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/struct-update-syntax-for-different-types/15636)

Comment: I'm glad this is only a duplicate of every *other* Rust forum, and not StackOverflow's. Thanks for the links, and the destructure suggestion.

Comment: @FauxFaux: I've had similar murderous thoughts with match statements, like `match optionT { Some(t) => Some(makeItU(t)), other => other }` which complains that `other` is not of type `Option<U>` even though "None" is the same atom in both cases; or similarly with differing lifetimes... when the remaining variants are all `'static`. Hopefully it's the kind of papercuts which will get better in time :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. That doesn't look like it would be covered by any of those existing RFCs, might be worth raising at a higher level, if you want it fixed? For the `Option` case, I suspect people will tell you to use `map`, or explicitly `None => None`, both of which would work.

Comment: @FauxFaux: I am not sure if there is any desire to "solve" the issue. It basically requires path-dependent typing which is a non-trivial addition to any language. As for Option, I merely used it for demonstration as it is familiar; on custom enums there is no `map`.