# Conveniently updating a struct's fields using a struct with a subset of the original struct's fields (Data transfer objects in Rust)

Tags: struct, rust

I'm currently trying to find out if there's a convenient way in Rust to update the fields of a struct A with a struct B, where the fields of struct B are basically a subset of the fields of struct A.

In practice I'd like to use an `UpdateUserDto` struct (used for JSON deserialization) to update the fields of a `User` struct, so I can save the updated `User` struct in a database.

Example:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Queryable, Identifiable, AsChangeset)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct User {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub email: String,
    pub name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize)]
pub struct UpdateUserDto{
    pub email: String,
    pub name: String,
}

...

// Current user from the database.
let mut user: User = db::users::get_by_id(...);

// Deserialized JSON data.
let update_user_data: UpdateUserData = ...;

// These are the cumbersome operations that I'd like to avoid.
user.email = update_user_dto.email;
user.name = update_user_dto.name;

// Saves the updated user in the database.
db::users::update(..., &user);
```

It doesn't seem to be the sort of operation that one usually does in Rust, since I couldn't find anything like this anywhere on the internet. But it's quite possible that I just haven't figured out what and where to look for...

Comment: is the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) good enough? `User { /* fields */ ..user }` [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54cf6a0c2346cb10b2f584628d7e42ee)

Comment: The struct update syntax can't be used between different types directly, but you may find the recommendation in this answer to be convenient: [Is there syntax for moving fields between similar structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962279/is-there-syntax-for-moving-fields-between-similar-structs)

Comment: I suppose this answers my question, but it doesn't fully satisfy me to be honest. This syntax would still get very ugly and inconvenient if the structs were larger. Thanks for the quick help though!