# How can I convert a struct to another struct with exactly the same field names and types?

Tags: struct, rust, type-conversion

I've got two identical structs with the same name, fields (and field types), that live in different modules. These are constructed by a derive macro and would like to easily convert from one to the other.

e.g.

```rust
mod a {
    struct A {
        field1: String,
        field2: String,
    }
}

mod b {
    struct A {
        field1: String,
        field2: String,
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do `let a: a::A = a::A::from(b::A)` or similar.

`impl From<b::A> for a::A` requires writing all the fields from both structs in the `from()` method. Is there any way to achieve this without all the associated boilerplate?

Comment: Can you tell more about that derive macro ? Maybe a MRE ?

Comment: [How to avoid code duplication of different structs with semantically equal fields/properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429218/155423); [Is there syntax for moving fields between similar structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50962279/155423)

Comment: @DenysSéguret These are structs constructed by the `graphql-client` crate. It creates structs for each query, but in my case I'm using a fragment for all queries so the resulting structs are all identical

Comment: related: https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/issues/312 but it doesn't look like they're managing to solve the refactoring problems

Comment: Thank you @DenysSéguret - I had seen the issue before, but had overlooked the workaround proposed in the description, which does the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use serde to serialize a struct to another Rust data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477967/how-can-i-use-serde-to-serialize-a-struct-to-another-rust-data-structure)

Comment: Yes, sort of, @Caesar. I ended up using serde, but within the `From` implementation (so I could actually do `let a: a::A = a::A::from(b::A)`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there syntax for moving fields between similar structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962279/is-there-syntax-for-moving-fields-between-similar-structs)

Comment: No, but thank you @ChayimFriedman. The post you suggest deals with two structs with similar parameters, instead of completely identical (which is what I was after)

Comment: That's true, but it makes no difference (you can use serialization, but I wouldn't recommend).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that until something like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2528) is implemented the only way to achieve this conversion is serialising:

```rust
impl From<b::A> for a::A {
    fn from(a: b::A) -> Self {
        let serialised = serde_json::to_string(&a).unwrap();
        serde_json::from_str(&serialised).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/pull/308#issuecomment-595876757)

Comment: It's more efficient to use `serde_json::Value` as the intermediary type – see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57488708) for an example.